# How to pull specific commit code from bitbucket-git

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using BitBucket-Git for my android application for version control. I have commited code five times.

Suppose I have done five commits v1, v2, v3, v4, v5. Now I want to get the complete source code till I have v3 commit only. Is there any way to get that?

I just simply want to pull complete code till v3.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't pull a single commit. Rather, clone the repository and checkout the commit you are interested in:

```
$ git clone <repo>
$ git checkout v1
```

This will create a detached `HEAD` state in your working copy, mirroring the state in commit `v1`.

If you want to continue committing from where `v1` ended, use a hard reset:

```
$ git reset --hard v1
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking Suppose I have done five commits v1, v2, v3, v4, v4. Now I want to get the complete source code till I have v3 commit only. Is there any way to get that ? I am not looking to continue committing from v3 end.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same query, this is how i solved it:

1.) Make a new branch in ur git directory:

```
git branch new-branch-name-here
```

2.) Switch into that branch

```
(git checkout new-branch-name-here)
```

3.) Once on that branch, type:

```
git reset commit-code-here --hard
```

(where commit-code-here is the commit name, in ur case v3.)

ull be back to that commit!